# Leshan connect to server and cloud

Tags: eclipse, iot, gateway, coap, leshan

I have the task of implementing iot device management using **Eclipse Leshan**. I have difficulty understanding how Eclipse Leshan works in connecting IOT sensors with **servers and cloud**. Is it true if I declare that **Eclipse Leshan** does not require a **gateway** like **Eclipse Kura** to connect into server and cloud?

Does anyone know where the complete documentation about Eclipse Leshan is? it would be very helpful if there were examples of programs in implementing the eclipse leshan.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Leshan is a library for implementing applications that use the LWM2M protocol to manage devices. As such, your application can use Leshan's Java API in order to interact with devices that also support LWM2M.

LWM2M does not per se mandate a transport protocol. However, the spec is written assuming that CoAP over UDP is used for that purpose. In fact, the *LW* in LWM2M stands for *Lightweight* and as such, using CoAP as the transport protocol makes a lot of sense for managing constrained devices.

Eclipse Leshan itself does not connect to a server or cloud but instead is usually part of an application that is hosted on a server (on the cloud). However, you need to implement that application yourself because Leshan, as indicated above, is just a library. The devices then interact with your LWM2M enabled application. Because CoAP/UDP uses standard IP, this interaction can occur over public internet infrastructure if desirable in your use case, i.e. no gateway is necessarily needed. You can, however, also connect your devices to a local gateway, e.g. Kura, and then connect the gateway to your LWM2M server in the cloud instead. It really depends on your use case and the capabilities of the devices.

Comment: Very thanks for the answer. Perhaps if you have the open project repository that implement about this one, can you share with me ?